# How can Avoid model popup is not showing when javascript validation is happening on page load in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using modelpop extender in my .aspx page. i want show this model popup when page is loading but not want to  showing when user enter wrong input in textbox. it will also showing modelpup when javascript validation is happeing. such as    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", " alert(\" Incorrect UserName OR Password \");

```
Default.aspx---
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ctlModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
                PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="imgOK" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FCFCFC; height: 200px;
                    width: 550px; text-align: left;">
                    <tr style="background: url('../Images/bg.jpg'); color: White;">
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                New Password Policy:-</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ClosePopupCls">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgOK" ImageUrl="~/Images/close3.png" Height="35px" Width="35px"
                                ToolTip="Close" runat="server" ImageAlign="Top" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p style="color: Red">
                                -Default Password: 123456<br />
                                -Password should be changed after loging through default password.<br />
                                -Password should be atleast 8 Characters and combination of Numeric, Alphabets (Caps
                                Small) and Special Characters.<br />
                                -Login will be blocked after 5 unsuccessful login attempts.
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {


        //ctlModalPopupExtender.Hide();
        //pnlpopup.Visible = false;
        GC.Collect();
        string defaultPassword = string.Empty;
        string expiryDate = string.Empty;
        string val = string.Empty;
        string uniqueSessionVal = string.Empty;
        int compDate = -99;
        DateTime todays_date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
        string todaysDate = string.Empty;
        todaysDate = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", todays_date);

        DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();

        //int sMonth, eMonth;
        Login oBll_Login = new Login();
        oBll_Login.Username = txtloginname.Text.Trim();

        //-------------Modified by Richa Agrwal - 16-Jan-2009 Change code for Password Encryption---------------
        string pass = BLLGeneral.Encrypt(txtPass.Text.Trim());
        oBll_Login.Password = BLLGeneral.Encrypt(txtPass.Text.Trim());
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (SessionInfo.DisplayName != string.Empty)
        {
            if (SessionInfo.DisplayName != txtloginname.Text.Trim())
            {
                _failureCount = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _failureCount = 0;
        }
        Session["User"] = txtloginname.Text;
        SessionInfo.LoginName = txtloginname.Text.Trim();
        SessionInfo.DisplayName = txtloginname.Text.Trim();
        SessionInfo.IsLoggedIn = false;
        SessionInfo.UnqSessionId = "NA";

        //--------------------------------------------------//  
        oDataTable = Login.GetUserIdLockValue(txtloginname.Text.Trim());
        if ((oDataTable.Rows.Count > 0) && (Convert.ToString(oDataTable.Rows[0][0]) == "T"))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "User ID is blocked! For new Password please click on UnBlock User ID!!";
            //btnChangePassword.Enabled = true;
            btnLogin.Enabled = false;
            //rfvPass.Enabled = false;
            _failureCount = 0;
            SessionInfo.IsLoggedIn = false;
            val = UpdateLoginStatus("F");
            if (val != "LogIn History Updation Successful!!")
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert('" + val + "'); </script>");
                return;
            }
            return;
        }
        else if (oDataTable.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            val = UpdateLoginStatus("F");
            if (val != "LogIn History Updation Successful!!")
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert('" + val + "'); </script>");
                return;
            }
        }

        //Check User Login Status
        //*********************************
        oDataTable = Login.GetUserLoginStatus(txtloginname.Text.Trim());
        if (oDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //              if(Convert.ToString(oDataTable.Rows[0][0]) == "T")
            //              {
            //                  ClearSession();
            //                   this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"k1","<script language=javascript> alert(\"User is already Logged IN!!\"); </script>");
            //                  SessionInfo.IsLoggedIn = false;
            //                  return;
            //              }
        }
        else
        {
            ClearSession();
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Incorrect UserName!\"); </script>");
            //lblMessage.Text = "Incorrect UserName";
            val = UpdateLoginStatus("F");
            if (val != "LogIn History Updation Successful!!")
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert('" + val + "'); </script>");
                return;
            }
            SessionInfo.IsLoggedIn = false;
            return;
        }
        //*********************************
        int loginId = oBll_Login.AuthenticateUser();
        if (loginId <= 0)
        {
            //Modified By Richa Agrwal - 21Feb2009 User ID will be locked if login failure attempt is greater than 5
            _failureCount++;
            val = UpdateLoginStatus("F");
            if (val != "LogIn History Updation Successful!!")
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert('" + val + "'); </script>");
                return;
            }
            //lblMessage.Text = "Invalid User Name / Password";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Invalid User Name / Password\"); </script>");

            if (_failureCount >= 5)
            {
                int cnt = Login.LockUserId(txtloginname.Text.Trim());
                if (cnt <= 0)
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Incorrect UserName OR Password! Exception Occured Please Contact your Application Administrator!!\"); </script>");
                    _failureCount = 0;
                    SessionInfo.IsLoggedIn = false;
                    return;
                }
                lblMessage.Text = "User ID is blocked! For new Password please click on UnBlock User ID!!";
                //btnChangePassword.Enabled = true;
                btnLogin.Enabled = false;
                //rfvPass.Enabled = false;
                _failureCount = 0;
            }
            SessionInfo.IsLoggedIn = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            SessionInfo.IsLoggedIn = true;


            System.Web.HttpCookie c = new System.Web.HttpCookie("Role", SessionInfo.Role);

            c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(90);
            Response.Cookies.Add(c);

            System.Web.HttpCookie cd = new System.Web.HttpCookie("UserName", SessionInfo.LoginName);
            cd.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(90);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cd);

            //Modified By Richa Agrwal - 16-Jan-2009 Get DefaultPassword Value from tbluserinfo
            //______________________________________________________________________________________
            oDataTable = Login.GetDefaultPasswordValue(txtloginname.Text.Trim());
            if (oDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                defaultPassword = Convert.ToString(oDataTable.Rows[0][0]);
            }
            //______________________________________________________________________________________
            //Get Expiry Date for Password
            oDataTable = Login.GetPasswordExpiryDate(txtloginname.Text.Trim());
            if ((oDataTable.Rows.Count > 0) && ((Convert.ToString(oDataTable.Rows[0][0]) != "01/01/2000") || (Convert.ToString(oDataTable.Rows[0][0]) != string.Empty)))
            {
                expiryDate = Convert.ToString(oDataTable.Rows[0][0]);
            }
            if (defaultPassword == "F")
            {
                compDate = BLLGeneral.CompareDate(todaysDate, expiryDate);
            }

            if ((defaultPassword == "F") && (compDate >= 0))
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Your Password Expires!! Please change your Password !\"); </script>");
                Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
            }

            //Update UserHitCount
            val = Login.UpdateUserHitCount(txtloginname.Text.Trim());
            if (val != "Login Successful!!")
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert('" + val + "'); </script>");
                return;
            }

            uniqueSessionVal = RandomPassword.Generate(20, 40);
            SessionInfo.UnqSessionId = uniqueSessionVal.Trim();

            val = UpdateLoginStatus("S");
            if (val != "LogIn History Updation Successful!!")
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert('" + val + "'); </script>");
                return;
            }

            //Updates Hit Count
            UpdateHiCount();

        }
        switch (oBll_Login.AuthenticateUser())
        {
            case 0:
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Incorrect UserName OR Password \"); </script>");
                break;
            case 1:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("InternalTransmittal.aspx");
                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("InternalTransmittal.aspx");
                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("DSSystem.aspx");
                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("SearchDocuments.aspx");


                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("SearchVendorDocuments.aspx");
                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("SearchShipment.aspx");
                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("onmdcc.aspx");
                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                if (defaultPassword == "F")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("onmnormaluser.aspx");
                }
                else if (defaultPassword == "T")
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "k1", "<script language=javascript> alert(\" Please change your Default Password !\"); </script>");
                    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```